# MonoTouch UIImageView hangs randomly

Tags: uiimageview, xamarin.ios

I'm having an issue whereby a `UIImageView` occasionally hangs, and I have to close the iPad simulator and relaunch.  The problem I'm seeing happens only sporadically, and the exact same code will work one time, and not the next.  The path to get to the hang point is always the same, as it happens soon after I've started the application up.  I've not deployed the app to an iPad yet, so I don't know if it's an issue once deployed, however it's incredibly frustrating.

I load an image into the `UIImageView` from disk, and the image hasn't been changed between starts etc, but it fails on the same line of code every time it hangs, which is:

```
_imageView.Image = image;
```

Where "image" is a loaded `UIImage`.

Difficult to understand why, does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Could you provide the code you use to retrieve that image?

Comment: UIImage's are not loaded immediately, they are delay-loaded until their contents are needed (in this case to paint the screen). It is possible that the image you loaded is corrupt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to work out what the issue was.  It was a threading issue of my own design. I was using a tag for each of my activity monitor views, however I was using the same tag for every activity monitor.  When I removed it, I was checking if the view existed before removing it, then removing it.  The issue was being caused when another thread tried to remove the tagged view at the same time as another thread tried to do the same, and it caused it to hang.

I've resolved this issue by using instance level variables for my activity monitor views, which means I only ever remove the view I require to remove, removing tagging altogether.  Obviously I could have also made every tag different instead, but I felt that the method I implemented was best for my solution.  Thanks for all your feedback!

Davoc

Answer (score 1):

> Difficult to understand why, does anyone have any ideas?

Those type of bugs are often related to other, previous, parts of the code **or** something specific to your setup (e.g. MonoTouch / iOS SDK and/or OSX versions).

The best way to get this fixed, or understand why it fails, would be to open a bug report at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com and attach a small, self-contained, test case that shows the *hang* even if it takes several execution to duplicate it (just explain this in the bug report).

Comment: The problem I have is that my application is tied in with non public web services at the moment, so it's not very easy to provide source for the issue until the web services are public.

Comment: It would be best to create a smaller subset of your application, the smaller the better (and the faster we can find the issue :-)

Comment: No problem, I'll do it next week (deadline for this is monday!)  Thanks

Comment: UIImage's are not loaded immediately, they are delay-loaded until their contents are needed (in this case to paint the screen).   It is possible that the image you loaded is corrupt.

Comment: I've reworked the code and have started manually rotating the image using a timer, now it hangs when I enable the timer.  The images can't be corrupt as they work fine in the app and I can open them from the iPhone simulator directories for the application.  Any ideas?

Comment: @davocbradley I suspect this could be related to updating UI element from another (non main) thread. But without seeing code it's only a *wild* guess.

Comment: Do you have somewhere I can send you some code?  I've removed all of my threading stuff and so far it seems to work ok, but it's frustrating that I need to remove the threading as that shows activity monitors etc elsewhere and works ok?

Comment: open a bug report at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com and add a link to this question (and your code as an attachment)